# How best to utilize two SSD disks on VPS webserver

Tags: web-server, ssd, debian-jessie

I would like to ask you about your opinions how to utilize two SSD disks on webserver.. I read many articles about raid, disk mounting, lvm, disk cache, etc. but still I am not sure how to decide which solution would be best for future using & utilization.. (I don't need do custom backups because of scheduled backups on provider side) See below for a brief description of the server. Thanks in advance for tips

Are there **also any other options than RAID**? There are any benefits of using SSD disk as cache storage on fully SSD server?

2 threads Xeon 1.70 GHz 8GB RAM 2× 60GB SSD Automatic internal + external backups Snapshots

SW - Debian 8, Apache, MariaDB, ISPConfig

Edit: Server is VPS

Comment: With 2 disks you have 3 options, no RAID, use each disk individually, RAID0 and RAID1 and if you care about your data and availability you really have only the one option.

Comment: Thank you, HBruijn. I'm sorry forgot to write that is VPS.. Data protection is provider's liability (they have RAIDed disk pools). Don't you have xperience of using disk for system caching?

Answer (score 0):

If this was my server, the RAID config would be dictated to by this question:

Is space and issue?

If the answer is yes I would use RAID0, if not RAID1.

Kobus

Comment: Thank you, Kobus. I am sorry I forgot to write that is VPS so disks are virtual and may be on same physical disk. Data protection is provider's liability (they have RAIDed disk pools) and I think that RAID1 is unnecessary in this case or am I wrong? So I thought about RAID 0 or JBOD, but RAID 0 seems better..

Comment: Kobus, don't you have experience of using disk for system caching?

Comment: If the system is a vps and the disks are virtual, raid goes out the window. In that case I would setup LVM, add both disks to the same volume group and just use it where it is needed. If you dont need all the space immediately, setup logical volumes so you can get started. The rest of the space can then be added as and when you need it.